# f.collection_select not working rails 3 (has_many/belongs_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for, form-helpers

I have two models: User and Company. A User belongs_to a company and a Company has_many users.

When a user signs up on the form I want there to be a list of companies that the User can select from and when the user is created the association with the company is created.

I figured collection_select would be the answer for this and it does populate the dropdown box  with the company names and I can select them, but it does not get passed to the User table and create the association, the Company_id column (foreign key) stays blank.

If I put f.collection_select I get the error: undefined method `merge' for :company_name:Symbol

I can't figure out how to get this to work after about a week or two of working on this and I can't find too much documentation on this. Please help! (If more code is needed please let me know!)

Signup form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<%= f.label :company, :class => 'col-left' %>
<%= f.collection_select(:user, :company_id, Company.all, :id, :company_name, {:include_blank => true}) %>
     <%= f.label :email, :class => 'col-left' %>
     <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'col-right' %>
     <%= f.label :name, :class => 'col-left' %>
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
     <%= f.label :password, :class => 'col-left' %>
     <%= f.password_field :password %>
     <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password", :class => 'col-left' %>
     <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
     <%= image_submit_tag "/assets/create-account.png" %>
     <% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In <%= f.collection_select(:user, ...) %>, "f" is your user => form_for(**@user**) do |f|

Did you try this ?

```
<%= f.collection_select(:company_id, Company.all, :id, :company_name, {:include_blank => true}) %>
```